# When does a kosher place need a mashgiach temidi?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, inspection

I notice that some kosher places have a mashgiach (kashrut inspector) that vsists the place occasionally. Others have someone there permanently.

What criteria is used to decide if a place needs a mashgiach temidi?

Comment: I think generally it's meat places that have a Mashgiach Temidi.

Comment: I would imagine if the cooks are not Jewish, that would be another reason to prefer a _mashgiach_ be there all the time.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I can't say if that's statistically true. But, as far as I know, many supermarkets have a mashgiach temidi as well. The mashgichim are supervising produce, fish and dairy products as well as meat, though meat is still the most labor-intensive with produce a close second. (I hope the lettuce these days doesn't have Zika!)

Comment: @Salmononius2, at least one of the local kosher (fleischig) places does not appear to have a mashgiach temidi. Despite this, their hashgacha is from the KVH, which is universally accepted in the Boston area.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt that's an interesting point. In viewing the answer from sabbahillel, are all the workers Jewish so that there is no problem of bishul akum?

Comment: @DanF, at least the owner is Jewish. Not all of the workers though.

Answer (score 1):

Given that many operations require complete knowledge and supervision of the processing, then a mashgiach would need to be present whenever ingredients are brought in to the plant and would have to be able to inspect the invoices as well as the ingredients.  Since a restaurant has constant production, then it would need a mashgiach tmidi (though there may be circumstances in which the owner might be trusted as a mashgiach tmidi) in order to avoid problems.

There is a story in which a hotel color coded its utensils blue (dairy) or red (meat) with spray paint on the handle. A mashgiach managed to stop one of the workers from (innocently) respraying some silverware when they needed some more. It was not a deliberate attempt to cheat, the worker just did not realize that it was not the color that was significant.

For example, the Star-K explains what is involved with fish fish [The Tell Tail Sign](http://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1115/the-tell-tail-sign/)

> The great posek Hador, R’ Moshe Feinstein, tz”l, writes in his
>   responsa that the proper way to given kosher certification to fish
>   productions is for the mashgiach to see every fish. Therefore, Star-K
>   certified salmon, as well as all other fish varieties, have a
>   mashigiach t’midi who examines every fish during production.
>
> The mashgiach has to position himself strategically in order to be
>   able to see all the fish before the skin is removed. Having the
>   workers check each fish individually is not sufficient. The mashgiach
>   must set up a system which ensures that each fish is inspected by him.
>
> To meet the requirements of bishul Yisroel, the mashgiach puts on the
>   steam after the fish has been rolled into a cold oven.
>
> After cooking, the mashgiach must be present for the canning and
>   labeling. In addition to the can code, a specific kosher code is added
>   as a siman (sign) that the fish was produced and canned in the
>   presence of a Star-K mashgiach. The producer’s labels, complete with
>   the certification symbol, have to be in the possession of the
>   mashgiach so that they would not be inadvertently used for a
>   non-supervised run.

Answer (score 0):

Every kashrut authority has their own criteria as to which places need a mashgiach temidi. For example, they may decide that if the owner him/herself is Shomer Shabbos they can be trusted and a yotzei v'nichnas (mashgiach who comes every so often) is enough. Or that the type of establishment determines e.g. a restaurant might need one, but a bakery might not (the mashgiach comes every few hours to sift the flour and take challa etc.). 
This might be a reason to prefer or not rely on a particular kashrus organization - if they are more willing to give kashrus certification without a mashgiach temidi.

Comment: Hi Miriam. This answer sounds credible. But, I'd like it strengthened by someone who is / was a mashgiach or info from a certification place. The criteria you describe sounds a bit random. I'm wondering if there is a set standard that most follow.

Comment: This answer is simply that each agency has its own criteria. While doubtless correct, that's not particularly informative.